# osm2pgsql error reading file

Tags: osm2pgsql

I am using the osm2pqsql utility to convert my osm file to PostgreSQL but it always stops showing the following error. How should I solve this problem?[image: Error shown]

Comment: Is there a space in the osm file name?

Comment: no. there is no space in the osm file name.

Comment: Have you tried to rename "ûc" into some ASCII-only name, like "uc" ?

Comment: I tried that but nothing happened. However, surprisingly, the problem went away after I restarted my PC.